# How to sign in to YouTube and Google with different accounts?

Tags: youtube, google-account

One of my accounts got cancelled and I can't sign in to YouTube because it redirects me to the cancelled account page. Also I can't use the YouTube email as my main account.

Is it possible to use one account for YouTube and another account for other Google services?

Comment: Go to your browser's preferences, find "Cookies" and delete all cookies associated with "YouTube".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use 2 different accounts you can use [Cookie Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-switcher/lbgngibmlgcicanoijcnijbkmjpkifkb?hl=en) or any other cookie extension.
First, sign out of all Google accounts and sign in to the account you want to use YouTube with.

Then, go to YouTube and save that cookie.

[image]

Sign out of all Google accounts again and sign in to your default account.

Lastly, go to YouTube, click Cookie Switcher and load the cookie.

Comment: for firefox there is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/?src=featured

Answer (score 4):

It seems quite *incredible* but this little trick **WORKS:**

1. Log out of both Gmail and YouTube.
2. Open a browser tab with the Gmail login page.
3. Open a browser tab with the YouTube login page.
4. Fill in your user credentials in each login page, but DO NOT log in
   yet. Make sure the text cursor is in the password field on both
   login pages.
5. Switch to the YouTube login page and press Enter to log in.
6. Quickly switch to the Gmail login page and press Enter to log in.

Note: Experiment which first to login, Google or Youtube. The correct order *changes*.

[ All credit goes to [Brother Lobster](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/_8VqfRz00Dc) from a Google forum thread ]

I've tried it in Vivaldi and Firefox, stable situation of being logged in, with one Google account on YouTube and ***another*** on Google, for a few weeks now; does **NOT** seem to work in Chrome.

Comment: First YouTube, then Google worked for me. The other way around did not at this time.

Comment: This worked for me: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/172490/how-to-sign-in-to-youtube-with-another-account-that-is-not-disabled/172491#172491

Answer (score 2):

A different answer suggests installing an extension "Cookie Switcher".

If I were you, I would first test whether *deleting* all of Google's cookies solves the problem. (How to do that will depend on which browser you use.) That is a less "drastic" change than installing an extension. An extension can interfere with the performance and even the security of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers nowadays supports *Incognito windows*, *Private browsing*, *InPrivate* or similarly named features (see [this list](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001378.htm) for how to invoke the feature in different browsers).

Since cookies don't leak between a normal and an ingocnito browser window, you could log in to Gmail in your "normal" browser window, and open an incognito/private window and log in to YouTube there.