# How to sign in to YouTube with another account that is not disabled?

Tags: youtube, google-account

This is an example.
My youtube account is disabled and I can't sign in with youtube with another account. It just redirects me to the cancelled account page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open this url and sign in with the account that is not disabled:

https://accounts.google.com/AddSession?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop%26hl%3Den%26next%3D%252F&hl=en&passive=false&service=youtube&uilel=0